# Pagination is "working", but links do not show up for navigating the pagination

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I can access `.../page/1`, `.../page/2`, `etc`... and it displays the posts so I know that the pagination is technically working, but the pagination links are not showing up.

**Timber**

```
use const Flynt\Archives\POST_TYPES;

global $paged;

if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
  $paged = 1;
}

$context = Timber::get_context();

$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'paged' => $paged
);

$context['events'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
$context['options'] = get_fields('options');

Timber::render('templates/classes-and-registration.twig', $context);
```

**Twig**

```
<ul class="pagination">
          {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{{ posts.pagination.prev.link }}" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
          {% for page in posts.pagination.pages %}
            <li class="page-item">
              {% if page.link %}
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.link }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
              {% else %}
                <span class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</span>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
          {% if posts.pagination.next %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="{{ posts.pagination.next.link }}" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you prepare your posts in PHP with this line:

```php
$context['events'] = new Timber\PostQuery($args);
```

However, in your pagination, you access pagination on `posts`, which might not exist yet. You will either have to rename `events` to `posts`, or access your pagination from `events` instead of `posts`.

```
{# … #}


{% for page in events.pagination.pages %}
<li class="page-item">
    {% if page.link %}
    <a class="page-link" href="{{ page.link }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    {% else %}
    <span class="{{page.class}}">{{ page.title }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}


{# … #}
```

Also, I see that in your `$args` array, you define both `posts_per_page` and `numberposts`. The `numberposts` arg is actually an alias of `posts_per_page`. You should probably only define `posts_per_page`.